# Can't use task.delay feature

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I want to use the `Task.Delay` feature to set a delay in my program. I read and found out it's only in .NET Framework 4.5+. So I went ahead and downloaded .NET Framework 4.5. Well I still can't use this bit of code.

I'm not sure why. Any thoughts? I'm new to this so sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm using Visual Studios 2010 Express C#. Thank you for any help offered! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2010 Express can only target .NET 4. Download the [latest edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and you should be set.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. I thought I might try that but I wanted to make sure before downloading the thing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a variety of things, but it sounds like you need to target .NET 4.5. Simply downloading .NET 4.5 doesn't tell your particular application that is should target that framework. You'll need to right-click on your solution and click properties, and then choose .NET Framework 4.5 as your Target Framework.

Edit: Asik beat me to it and was correct, I didn't even think about that. Once you download the latest version, you'll still need to change your target framework.

Comment: I thought this too might have been the issue, but again wasn't sure. Nor did I know how to get it to target it. Thanks!